# How to call getSupportActionBar() for API 7 , in My Activity Class i can't call getSupportActionBar() Method

Tags: android

Anyone Please help me i m new for ActionBar

How to call getSupportActionBar() for API 7 , in My Activity Class i can't call getSupportActionBar() Method.

Comment: without your code i can only guess that you are trying to call getSupportActionBar() in Activity instead of FragmentActivity

Comment: do you reference appcompat in your project ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't Worry Its Very Simple :=-

At the place of (Activity) you have to extends ActionBarActivity & in your AndroidMainfest file android:minSdkVersion="7" .Now you can easily able to use getSupportActionBar() for API 7.

I hope it's helpful 4 u :)